# Hard Drives in Startech Enclosure Are Not Recognized

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, hard-drive

Issue 1 With Computer 1(Running Ubuntu 12.0.4)?

I have 8 external hard drives of varying sizes from different manufactureres that are formatted as either ntfs/ext4. We purchased a Startech 8-bay enclosure and I plugged all these 8 drives into this enclosure. Only the drive in first slot is being mounted and the remaining 7 doesn't come up. When I do sudo fdisk, I get an input/output error for any of these 7. But when I interchange drive 2 to slot 1 and drive 1 to slot2, the drive 2 mounts well and drive 1 gives input/output error. I even edited my /etc/fstab with new /dev labels and the problem is still persistent. When I interchange all the drives to slot1, they all mount well. But if I put them in other slots, they don't mount.

Issue 2 With Computer 2 (Running Ubuntu 12.0.4)?

Similar as above, I plugged 8 drives into it. Only the drives in slots 1, 3, 4 are being mounted. Drives in slots 2,5,6,7,8 do not mount. But if I put these unmounting drives in either of slots 1,3,4 they all work.

P.S: There are UIDs added for these drives before using them in enclosure. All these drives were connected individually using external drive docks to the computer.

Any pointers/comments/thoughts are highly appreciated.